# Gurobi using Python: Interpolation Function in Objective Function with Variables

Tags: python, optimization, interpolation, gurobi, lookup-tables

I am trying to use Gurobi to minimize the fuel consumption of diesel generators. The instantaneous fuel consumption of each diesel generator is calculated using interpolation from a meshgrid of sample values based on generator load and capacity (i.e. 70% load and 20kW capacity). This function is created as seen below:

```
Fuel_Map_X, Fuel_Map_Y = np.meshgrid(Fuel_Map_Load,Fuel_Map_Size)
f = interpolate.interp2d(Fuel_Map_X,Fuel_Map_Y,Fuel_Map_Data,kind='linear')
Testvalue = f(0.7,20)
```

So the output of TestValue is the instantaneous fuel consumption for a specified generator. Now, in my Gurobi model, both the load and capacity of each generator are variables. The sum of the fuel consumption  from all generators is what needs to be minimized. When I try to calculate the fuel consumption using the interpolation function and the variables as inputs, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Does anyone know if there is a work-around so I can use the interpolation function with variables as inputs? I tried making the fuel consumption a constraint instead of the objective and received the same error.

Upon request, here is how I have defined the pertinent variables using Gurobi and form them into the desired objective function (which does not work):

```
# Defining Gurobi Variables
Load1 = m.addVars(T,name="Load1")
Cap1 = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER,name="Cap1") # Capacity of Cat. 1 component chosen


# Gurobi Objective Function
obj = sum(f(Load1[t],Cap1) for t in range(T))
m.setObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

Also, you can assume that the variables have been calculated successfully, and there are constraints, but they don't matter as they have zero impact on my issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post more of your code, specifically the part that uses the f function?

Comment: @GregGlockner I have added this to my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gurobi is designed to solve mixed-integer problems with quadratic or linear expressions, so it can only solve models that fit into one of [its canonical forms](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013156432-What-types-of-models-can-Gurobi-solve-). Try to convert your function f() into a piecewise linear expression.